# Audio streaming from microphone to Speaker in iphone xcode

Tags: iphone, audio-streaming, broadcast, microphone, speaker

Actually i'm a newbee to iOS development.
My requirement from a client is to make iPhone work as a MegaPhone. i.e, Audio input should be taken from the bluetooth or microphone and broadcast it through phone speakers.

I am able to record audio from microphone and play it using AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer,but what actually i needed is to broadcast to the speakers not recording.

Guys any sample codes available for this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AurioTouch sample code is available for this purpose

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html